# How measure time after an event in Unity (2D)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game in which I would like to show a timer for the user, which will show the elapsed time since the touch of the character.  I have found a workaround which firstly seemed to be great, but after go to the menu in my game, start again the playing (not with stop the game in Unity), I haven't got the 1, 2, 3... seconds, but a bigger time. I think the problem is with using Time.time which is use the elapsed time from the project start (as far as I know), and I can't null it.

Here is my code for measuring time:

```
elapsedTime = Time.time - startTime;
```

and I have the elapsedTime and startTime variables in the script as float.

How can I solve this problem? Could you show me maybe better code to measure time after an event?

Comment: I see no problem with what you're doing. You just store the time of the event as you start time, and then subtract that from whatever time you're at. If something is going wrong, you're either not correctly setting your variables correctly, or something is done in your Menu code which is problematic.

Comment: For more accurate timing, you should use the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways you could do this.

Using your current method, you could cache a float that represent the current time from when you start the game from the menu (Let's call it `continueTime`).
This will account for going back to menu system etc as you can always get the delta between by doing the following:

```
currentTime = Time.time - continueTime; // this will be the equivalent of elapsed time since you started this iteration of the game.
```

You could even make a method just for this purpose:

```
public static float GetCurrentTimeOffset(float continueTime)
{
    return Time.time - continueTime;
}
```

How you cached the time is up to you, but it's one way to do it.

From there, you'd be able to do a comparison of your elapsed time by using the normal method:

```
elapsedTime = GetCurrentTimeOffset(continueTime) - startTime;
```

This isn't the only way to do it, but an example. Using a coroutine may be of use too. Here's an example of a coroutine function that you could manipulate for you purposes as well. Feel free to ask questions if you have some and i'll do my best to clarify!

```
// Parameter: seconds is the time delay between touching the character and 
// returning out of the coroutine. 
public IEnumerator TouchTimer(int seconds)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres an example of what i think you want. A bit unclear but just attach this to an object, set timer to true to start it and timer to false to stop it. The example runs for ten seconds printing to the Debug.Log and stops.

```
#pragma strict

        var timer : boolean = false;
        var tTime : float;

       function Update()
    {
          if (timer)
          {
            tTime += Time.deltaTime;
          } 
          else 
          {
              tTime = 0; // Reset
          }
          Debug.Log(tTime);
        }

        function Start () 
        {
            timer = true;
            yield WaitForSeconds(10);
            timer = false;
        }
```